# PG::Error FATAL: password authentication failed for user

Tags: windows, postgresql, rubymine

I am using Windows. Just created a new project in RubyMine. Installed Postgresql for Windows, created a password. When i try to start the project it shows me: PG::Error FATAL: password authentication failed for user. Could you tell me what i am doing wrong. I have never worked with Postgresql before.

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: shop_development
  pool: 5
  username: name of the project
  password: my password
```

Comment: Which part of the error message is not clear? You provided bad username or bad password.

Comment: I know. Could you tell me: username should be the name as project name and password is the same as created during postgresql install, right?

Comment: have you tried loggin into that user on the command line? Use: `psql shop_development <username>` and see if you can get in with the password you think is set.  Failing that you may need to reset the password or create the user if you havn't already.  The super user on PostgreSQL is `postgres` and you should have set the password for this during installation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, since all this stuff is new to me, my mistake was that i did not create a user first:)

Answer (score 0):

I know you already got your answer so this is for posterity sake, namely how to troubleshoot password failed issues.

1. Check to make sure the user exists.  Use psql to log in.  You may get an error which says that the role is unknown which means that the user does not exist.  Creating it should solve the problem (as it did in your case).
2. If that doesn't work try resetting the password.  Log in with another user in psql and run

   ```
     ALTER USER myuser WITH PASSWORD 'mysecretpassword';
   ```
3. If that doesn't fix it, the password may have expired.  This is most common on systems where someone else created the users and set expiration dates for the passwords.  Try:

   ```
    ALTER USER myuser WITH VALID UNTIL 'infinity';
   ```

If that doesn't work, check to make sure you are in fact logging into the db server you think you are.